# C++ can setw and setfill pad the end of a string?

Tags: c++, formatting, setw

Is there a way to make `setw` and `setfill` pad the end of a string instead of the front?

I have a situation where I'm printing something like this.

```
 CONSTANT TEXT variablesizeName1 .....:number1 

 CONSTANT TEXT varsizeName2 ..........:number2
```

I want to add a variable amount of `'.'` to the end of

`"CONSTANT TEXT variablesizeName#"` so I can make `":number#"` line up on the screen.

Note: I have an array of `"variablesizeName#"` so I know the widest case.

Or

Should I do it manually by setting `setw` like this

```cpp
for( int x= 0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x++)
{
string temp = string("CONSTANT TEXT ")+variabletext[x];
cout <<  temp;
cout << setw(MAXWIDTH - temp.length) << setfill('.') <<":";
cout << Number<<"\n";
}
```

I guess this would do the job but it feels kind of clunky.

Ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use manipulators [`std::left`, `std::right`, and `std::internal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) to choose where the fill characters go.

For your specific case, something like this could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

const char* C_TEXT = "Constant text ";
const size_t MAXWIDTH = 10;

void print(const std::string& var_text, int num)
{
    std::cout << C_TEXT
              // align output to left, fill goes to right
              << std::left << std::setw(MAXWIDTH) << std::setfill('.')
              << var_text << ": " << num << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print("1234567890", 42);
    print("12345", 101);
}
```

Output:

```
Constant text 1234567890: 42
Constant text 12345.....: 101
```

**EDIT**:
As mentioned in the link, `std::internal` works only with integer, floating point and monetary output. For example with negative integers, it'll insert fill characters between negative sign and left-most digit.

This:

```
int32_t i = -1;
std::cout << std::internal
          << std::setfill('0')
          << std::setw(11)  // max 10 digits + negative sign
          << i << '\n';
i = -123;
std::cout << std::internal
          << std::setfill('0')
          << std::setw(11)
          << i;
```

will output

```
-0000000001
-0000000123
```

Comment: Awesome. As a follow up to your answer, how does `std::internal` work?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
cout << left << setw(MAXWIDTH) << setfill('.') << temp << ':' << Number << endl;
```

Produces something like:

```
derp..........................:234
herpderpborp..................:12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
   std::cout
      << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left) // left align this section
      << std::setw(30)                    // within a max of 30 characters
      << std::setfill('.')                // fill with .
      << "Hello World!"
      << "\n";
}

//Output:
Hello World!..................
```