# Columns auto alignment C++

Tags: c++, tabular

I'm new in C++. I create a project that ask user to input their name, age, handphone number and university.

The code seems like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
vector<string>name;
vector<string>age;
vector<string>hpno;
vector<string>university;

string sname, sage, shpno, suniversity;

cout << "Enter name:" << endl;
getline(cin, sname);
name.push_back(sname);

cout << "Enter age:" << endl;
getline(cin, sage);
age.push_back(sage); 

cout << "Enter phone number:" << endl;
getline(cin, shpno);
hpno.push_back(shpno);

cout << "Enter university:" << endl;
getline(cin, suniversity);
university.push_back(suniversity);

cout << "Name" <<" "<< "Age" <<" "<< "Handphone Number" <<" "<< "University" 
     <<endl;    

for (int j = 0 ; j <= name.size() - 1 ; j++){
cout << name[j] << " " << age[j] << " " << hpno[j] << " " << 
university[j]<<endl;}

}
```

Let say the user input is like this:

Name: John Cena
Age: 20
Phone Number: 1234568903
University: Multimedia Univeristy

The Output that I want is like this:
`Name       Age  Phone Number  University 
 John Cena  20   1234568903    Multimedia University`

---

But the Output that I get is like this:
`Name   Age   Phone Number   University
  John Cena  20  1234568903  Multimedia University`

How to make the width of header synchronize with the width of content ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should set the width.
For that in c++, there is setw(). use that

http://www.c4learn.com/cplusplus/cpp-setw-setting-field-width/

follow this link

Comment: Why don't you explain its usage in your answer, instead?

Answer (score 1):

First include the missing `<string>` header, don't rely on *free rides* from other headers. Then utilize the [std::left](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) and [std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) stream manipulators on both the title and the data output:

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(10) << "Name"
    << std::setw(10) << "Age"
    << std::setw(20) << "Handphone Number"
    << std::setw(10) << "University"
    << std::endl;

for (int j = 0; j <= name.size() - 1; j++){
    cout << std::setw(10) << name[j]
        << std::setw(10) << age[j] 
        << std::setw(20) << hpno[j] 
        << std::setw(10) << university[j] << endl;
}
```

Note: some manipulators are persistent and need to be included only once, others are not and need to be included multiple times. [Avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) the `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need std::setw(), std::setfill('*'). Follow this links and read documentation.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/29761/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/right/

[C++ can setw and setfill pad the end of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062318/c-can-setw-and-setfill-pad-the-end-of-a-string)